# Android Studio exporting Android library project as jar

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm developing Android Library project. In Eclipse when I want to export it as a `jar` file:

1. Right click on Project->Export->Java->Jar file
2. I select manually some packages from the `src` and thats it (no `res` etc!) - This is the requirements from my Library...
3. In the checkboxes I check: "Export generated class files and resources". And that's it.

Now I migrated to Android Studio, so following some SO discussions I came up with this under `gradle.build`:

```
task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/outputs/mysdk.jar'
}

task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('build/outputs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'mysdk.jar')
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar, build)
```

When I then integrate the Jar in some Android App things not working indicating something went wrong with the process of exporting the Jar (The library project is free of errors/warnings etc.).

How to achieve similar behaviour of export to jar of eclipse in Android Studio?

Thanks,

Comment: You can export your library project as a Jar only if it doesn't have any associated resource. Does your library project contain Android resources (strings, layouts and so on)?

Comment: Yes actually a lot... We make full SDK

Comment: So you can't just export the jar but you need to distribute the `.aar`.

Comment: Thanks, And what should do our customers who are using Eclipse for the dev of their apps that make use of our SDK?

Comment: They should do it manually: https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html

Comment: It's easy in ideal world, in practice if your customer has some code and because of you-some contractor that decided to follow up best practices recommended by Google, they now need to modify their own code and environment... well that's not good for business

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to produce a `jar` file as the `res/` folder will be missing and anything that references the `R` file in your code will fail when executed.  This is because the `jar` format doesn't support android `res`.  You want your build to instead target `aar` format.  This is simple using gradle.  Instead of applying the application plugin (`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`) just apply the library plugin (`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`).

Then the `gradle build` will produce an `aar` file which will contain all your resources.

Developers who are still using eclipse will be familiar with how to import `aar` files because that is the android standard.  If they have not learned yet there are plenty of SO posts to help.

Developers who are using gradle or maven will have no problems consuming your sdk